# Animate elements into the page when scrolling down Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using Angular.js with Bootstrap, there is no jQuery in the project.

I want to use animate.css to fade in elements on the screen when scrolling up and down.

I have found the following example that demonstrates exactly what i need to achieve:

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB01649B4

How can i do this with Angular and animate.css, are there any tutorials on this or any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: try to used angularJs animation

Answer (score 1):

The animation itself can be done with only animate.css. If you want it to trigger when scrolling down however, you are going to need javascript or jQuery to let the browser know when to trigger the event.

A very easy library to use for this purpose is jquery-waypoint. It simply gives you a jquery hook when you reach a certain point in the browser. You can use that hook to start the animation.
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

The site has a couple of examples on it and some good documentation. If you don't feel like using a library specially for that, there are some decent tutorials that do it without plugin.

Edit: a nice blogpost on creating your own, without an extra pluging: http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/07/07/webpage-scrolling-animation-effects-css3-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

i belive what you looking is WOW js, a library designed to trigger animations as soon as you scroll to the element, is Jquery and Non Jquery versions and it plays nice with `Animate CSS` you can delay the trigger if you need it for the elements

More Info and Download:
[WOW JS WebSite](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)